# Dedicated SSD/HDD to install Windows on a MacBook

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bootcamp, ssd, partition

So I have a Late 2008 unibody MacBook. I recently bought a caddy to replace my optical drive with so I can fit a secondary drive in the laptop.

I have a 256 SSD in the main and a brand new 128 SSD to go in the caddy. Ideally I would like to have a Boot Camp install, but really don't want to go playing with the 256 SSD in the main drive with Mac OS X on, for more than one reason - but mainly as I do not have the space on there for the required partition.

Is there anyway to get a Boot Camp setup where the Windows install is on its own disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, feeling a bit silly answering my own question. But this was quite easy.

So I had two SSD's, one had Mac OS X installed on and was running fine. Because I was putting my second SSD in place of the super drive, but I needed the super drive to install windows-I first removed my Mac OS X SSD and put my to-be-Windows on in it's place.

So my machine had one blank SSD in. Inserted the windows disc to install, got windows on and updated. At this point I had a mac with just windows installed.

Then I swapped the super drive for my windows SSD and put the mac SSD in the main drive slot. From there just press alt on boot-up :D

Comment: FWIW: You can buy an external enclosure for your old SuperDrive relatively cheap. No reason to waste good hardware, and then when you need to actual use a disc, you just plug it into USB instead of opening up your machine and swapping drives

Comment: Oh, I'd already bought one but I didn't wanna wait :D The superdrive was already in as the 2nd SSD is new, and I only fancied swapping it the one time!

Comment: When did bootcamp come into this...  I'm asking because I have to do the same

Comment: It's funny really, I use bootcamp but not the boot camp assistant. So do what I said above, when booting (after the chime) hold alt and choose the drive you want to boot from. Then in windows, install bootcamp from online or your mac osx disk.